# is using both Nyquist's and Shannon's Theorem possible?

Tags: signal, communication, signal-processing, digital-communications, sampling

For instance, say I have a cable bandwidth of 1 MHz, and a signal-to-noise ratio of 255, how would I calculate the maximum bit rate possible if I were to be transmitting data via this cable using 4 signal levels?

Using Nyquist's I would get the maximum data rate 2 x 1 x log2(4) = 4 bps, and Shannon's would be 1 x log2(1+255) = 8 bps, but how would I combine them if I were to calculate the maximum bit rate possible when transmitting through this cable using 4 signal levels?

Comment: Shannon tells you the upper limit that is possible given a certain bandwidth and SNR. It is not a guarantee that you can attain that limit. It just tells you that it is impossible to attain a higher rate. It does not tell you whether you should use 2 levels or 100 or whatever. Shannon doesn't know or care what modulation scheme you are using. It is kind of like conservation of energy for data systems.

Comment: You must also use Hartley’s Theorem which indicates number of levels supported by SNR of 255 is almost 16 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem thereby increasing your bit rate or as you asked with 4 levels the effect on SNR vs BER for the demodulator type

Answer (score 2):

Your Nyquist formula has a trivial error: it's Mbps, not Bps. It also says that you have a symbol rate (baud rate) of 2x the bandwidth, which I don't think is right -- you need 2x the data rate as sample rate, but that's already considered in the "MHz bandwidth" measurement, so the "bandwidth" in your description is the "baud rate" AFAICT.

Your Shannon limit description doesn't include the requirement that you only use 4 levels. The Shannon limit tells you how much information you can jam through if you were to use "all levels possible" (given the S/N ratio.)

You can think of 4 levels as a two-bit "word" and the 1 MHz bandwidth as the ability to modulate/demodulate one 2-bit word every microsecond, leading to 2 Mbps throughput.